# ios would new app version update affect data stored in userdefault in old version?

Tags: ios, version

Say I have a app already online in app store, and it stored a some data, say a NSnumber in userdefault. Then I submit the second version to app store, and if user updates to this version, would the data be gone? or it will still be stored in userdefault with the same value?

Also the same situation for coredata data. If user created some data in coredata database, and then update to new version, would those data be gone? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates to an app do not interfere with NSUserDefaults or Coredata. As long as the app is not deleted it will maintain data stored.